# How do I get these two functions to work with Ajax, and how to I rewrite it in Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

function ajaxFunction(phpFunction){
        var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

```
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
    $('.subCat').html(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    $('.subCat').ready(function(){
    $('.subCat').fadeIn();
    });





        }
    }


    var url = "products.php?func=" + phpFunction;

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 

}
```

This function works great, and has no problems. But if I add:

```
function refreshProduct(idNum, phpFunction){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        $('.' + idNum).empty();
    $('.' + idNum).html(ajaxRequest.responseText);

    });





        }
    }


    var url = "products.php?func=" + phpFunction + "&idNum=" + idNum;

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 

}
```

When I try to execute `ajaxFunction('returnAllProducts')` I get:

```
    syntax error
 });\n
```

from

```
   $('.' + idNum).html(ajaxRequest.responseText);

    }); <<<----
```

and

```
ajaxFunction is not defined
javascript:ajaxFunction('returnAllProducts')()
```

So my questions are:

**a)** how do I convert this over to jquery? I've read over some jquery ajax tutorials, but I wasn't able to make the connection how to do what I am doing here.
**b)** How do I get both functions to work? I know the PHP behind them works fine, but I can't even test if `refreshProduct()` works properly right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a }

this is your code, properly indented...

```
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        $('.'idNum).empty();
        $('.'idNum).html(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    });
```

When it should be

```
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        $('.'idNum).empty();
        $('.'idNum).html(ajaxRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

Also, the two } after this should be deleted, rendering your code like this:

```
function refreshProduct(idNum, phpFunction){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            $('.' + idNum).empty();
            $('.' + idNum).html(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        }
    });

    var url = "products.php?func=" + phpFunction + "&idNum=" + idNum;

    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

As for rewriting this using jQuery, it's really easy:

```
function ajaxFunction(phpFunction){
    var url = "products.php?func=" + phpFunction;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('.subCat').html(data).ready(function(){
            $('.subCat').fadeIn();
        });
    });
}

function refreshProduct(idNum, phpFunction){
    var url = "products.php?func=" + phpFunction + "&idNum=" + idNum;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('.' + idNum).empty().html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Gah!  I like the re-write, but please use some selector storage and chaining!  Like `$('.' + idNum).empty().html(data);`

Comment: Actually, $.get is not really equivalent since it doesn't provide error handling, you would need to use $.ajax